# Create angular app without using angular-cli

Tags: angular, typescript

Good night.
Can anyone give me instructions (or links to articles) on how to create an angular project 4 from scratch, without using angular-cli?

I am a beginner in language and need to learn how to create an application without -cli.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you'd better  to start an Angular project by Angular-Cli. It faster and complete. 
So you can follow the documents of Angular website to read and try coding by yourself.

But if you really want to start the project without angular-cli. You can follow the below dcoument
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/setting-up-angular-from-scratch-1f518c65d8ab

Comment: Link given does not work - gives a certificate error